# Making department mandatory on all transactions using script

Tags: netsuite

We had to change the setup and uncheck ‘Make Departments Mandatory’ from the setup due to a bug in MRP system which does not work when this check box is checked. Now that we got the MRP working, I wanted to write a custom code/script to make department mandatory on all the transactions at the time of saving the record.

I went through the transactions that have department field on them and there are 34 of them.

Is there an easier way out to achieve this, rather than writing a different workflow for each type of transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without code by updating the custom form for each transaction, but that can be tedious and only works within the user-interface.

With a user event script, you can mark the department as mandatory before loading the record.  You can create a single script and deploy it to your 34 transactions.

An overly simplified script to mark the header-level department field as mandatory might look like this:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define(['N/log'], function(log) {
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE && context.type !== context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
            return;
        }

        const form = context.form;
        const departmentField = form.getField({ id: 'department' });

        if (departmentField) {
            departmentField.isMandatory = true;
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
    };
});
```

You can use similar logic to mark department fields mandatory on sublist lines as well.